# Count points in a grid

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I have a grid that I have created and a path that is there. I want to calculate the number of points each grid has or I want to calculate the number of points each slab or rectangle has.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! You have a QGIS algorithm for that : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#count-points-in-polygon

Comment: If the grid is made of polygons, have you tried points in polygon ?

Answer (score 4):

Use this expression on the grid layer:

```
array_length (overlay_contains ('point_layer', $id))
```